# How do I emulate network load to test connectivity between two servers?

Tags: testing, networking, integration-testing

I’m suspecting a network issue between 2 servers of my application. How can i test this network leg? Simplest solution please, maybe a test application?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple ping between the devices to check for packet loss and you have tools like hping for advanced test of tcp and other protocols. Another recommended tool for checking performance is iperf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf